# How to edit entity using FileType already uploaded?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to edit a shop entity with a cover image ( Image Entity ).
But I can't catch and use the File already uploaded.

I already Try all method found on internet so don't judge the state of my code :).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ShopRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * 
 */
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $google_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lat;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $longi;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Email(message="Veuillez renseigner un email valide !")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $mobile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fax;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hours = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $access_level;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $introduction;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="shops")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image", orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="shop")
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="shop", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $enable;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Promotions", mappedBy="shop", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $promotions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="shops")
     * @Groups({"shop"})
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $website;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image", inversedBy="coverShop", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $cover;




    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->owner = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bookings = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->promotions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeSlug() 
    {
        if(empty($this->slug))
        {
            $slugify = new Slugify();
            $this->slug = $slugify->slugify($this->name);
        }
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getGoogleId(): ?string
    {
        return $this->google_id;
    }

    public function setGoogleId(?string $google_id): self
    {
        $this->google_id = $google_id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLat(): ?float
    {
        return $this->lat;
    }

    public function setLat(?float $lat): self
    {
        $this->lat = $lat;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLongi(): ?string
    {
        return $this->longi;
    }

    public function setLongi(?string $longi): self
    {
        $this->longi = $longi;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?int
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(?int $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMobile(): ?int
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }

    public function setMobile(int $mobile): self
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFax(): ?int
    {
        return $this->fax;
    }

    public function setFax(?int $fax): self
    {
        $this->fax = $fax;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHours(): ?array
    {
        return $this->hours;
    }

    public function setHours(array $hours): self
    {
        $this->hours = $hours;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccessLevel(): ?int
    {
        return $this->access_level;
    }

    public function setAccessLevel(int $access_level): self
    {
        $this->access_level = $access_level;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIntroduction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->introduction;
    }

    public function setIntroduction(string $introduction): self
    {
        $this->introduction = $introduction;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCoverImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->coverImage;
    }

    public function setCoverImage(string $coverImage): self
    {
        $this->coverImage = $coverImage;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getOwner(): ?User
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    public function setOwner(?User $owner): self
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Image[]
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images[] = $image;
            $image->setShop($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if ($this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getShop() === $this) {
                $image->setShop(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[] = $product;
            $product->setShop($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($product->getShop() === $this) {
                $product->setShop(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnable(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->enable;
    }

    public function setEnable(?bool $enable): self
    {
        $this->enable = $enable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Promotions[]
     */
    public function getPromotions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->promotions;
    }

    public function addPromotion(Promotions $promotion): self
    {
        if (!$this->promotions->contains($promotion)) {
            $this->promotions[] = $promotion;
            $promotion->setShop($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePromotion(Promotions $promotion): self
    {
        if ($this->promotions->contains($promotion)) {
            $this->promotions->removeElement($promotion);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($promotion->getShop() === $this) {
                $promotion->setShop(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWebsite(): ?string
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    public function setWebsite(?string $website): self
    {
        $this->website = $website;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCover(): ?Image
    {
        return $this->cover;
    }

    public function setCover(?Image $cover): self
    {
        $this->cover = $cover;

        return $this;
    }




}
```

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png", "image/jpeg" })
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $caption;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Shop", inversedBy="images")
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Promotions", inversedBy="images")
     */
    private $promotions;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="images")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Shop", mappedBy="cover", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $coverShop;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    public function setUrl(string $url): self
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFile(): ?string
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile(string $file): self
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCaption(): ?string
    {
        return $this->caption;
    }

    public function setCaption(string $caption): self
    {
        $this->caption = $caption;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShop(): ?Shop
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }

    public function setShop(?Shop $shop): self
    {
        $this->shop = $shop;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPromotions(): ?Promotions
    {
        return $this->promotions;
    }

    public function setPromotions(?Promotions $promotions): self
    {
        $this->promotions = $promotions;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCoverShop(): ?Shop
    {
        return $this->coverShop;
    }

    public function setCoverShop(?Shop $coverShop): self
    {
        $this->coverShop = $coverShop;

        // set (or unset) the owning side of the relation if necessary
        $newCover = $coverShop === null ? null : $this;
        if ($newCover !== $coverShop->getCover()) {
            $coverShop->setCover($newCover);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

```
class ShopType extends ApplicationType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Nom","Tapez le nom de votre magasin"))
            ->add('category', 
                EntityType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Catégorie","Indiquer la categorie dans laquelle se situ votre magasin", [
                'required' => true,
                'class'    => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name'
            ]))
            ->add('slug', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Slug","Taper l\adresse web ( automatique )", [
                    'required' => false
                ]))
            ->add('introduction', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Introduction","Donnez une courte description de l'annonce"))
            ->add('description', 
                TextareaType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Descritpion détaillée","Indiquez la description complete de votre logement"))
            ->add('cover', 
                ImageType::class)
            ->add('address', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Adresse","Indiquez l'adresse du magasin"))
            ->add('email', 
                EmailType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Adresse mail","Indiquez votre adresse mail", [
                    'required' => true
                ]))
            ->add('phone', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Téléphone fixe","Indiquez votre numéro de téléphone", [
                    'required' => false
                ]))
            ->add('mobile', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Téléphone mobile","Indiquez votre numéro de téléphone portable"))
            ->add('website', 
                TextType::class, 
                $this->getConfiguration("Site Internet","Indiquez l'adresse de votre site internet professionnel", [
                    'required' => false
                ]))
            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, 
            [
                'entry_type' => ImageType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([

        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('url', FileType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Photo de couverture (png, jpeg)',
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Image::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
{% extends '/manage/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Modification d'une annonce{% endblock %}

{# Indique que l'on utilise un theme dans le fichier #}
{% form_theme form '/manage/shop/_collection.html.twig' %}

{% block bodybody %}
<div class="container">


    <h1>Modifier l'annonce : {{ shop.name }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="hidden" id="widget-counter" value="0"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Enreigstrer </button>

    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>

{% endblock %}



{% block javascripts %}

<script src="/js/shop.js">

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

```
{% block _shop_cover_widget %}
{{ dump(form.vars)}}
{{ form_widget(form.url, {'attr': {'value': form.vars.value.url , 'placeholder' : form.vars.value.url }}) }}   
{%- endblock _shop_cover_widget %}
```

```
/**
     * Edit an announce
     *
     * @Route ("/shops/{slug}/edit", name="shop_edit")
     * 
     * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER') and user === shop.getOwner()", message="Ce magasin ne vous appartient pas, vous ne pouvez pas le modifier" )
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Shop $shop, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager) 
    {
        $cover = $shop->getCover();
        $cover->setUrl(
            new File($this->getParameter('coverImages_directory').'/'.$shop->getCover()->getUrl())
        );

        $shop->setCover($cover);

        $form = $this->createForm(ShopType::class, $shop);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            if(null === $form->get('cover')->get('url')->getData())
            {
                $cover->setUrl(
                    new UploadedFile($this->getParameter('coverImages_directory').'/'.$shop->getCover()->getUrl())
                );

                $shop->setCover($cover);
            }
            else
            {
                // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
                /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */

                $file = $form->get('cover')->get('url')->getData();
                $realName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $cover->setCaption($realName);
                $fileName = $this->generateUniqueFileName().'.'.$file->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
                try {
                    $file->move(
                        $this->getParameter('coverImages_directory'),
                        $fileName
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    // ... handle exception if something happens during file upload
                }
                $cover->setUrl($fileName);
                $shop->setCover($cover);

            }


            $manager->persist($shop);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                "Les modifications de  <strong>{$shop->getName()}</strong> ont été ajouté avec succes!"
            ); 

            return $this->redirectToRoute('manage_home', [
                'slug' => $shop->getSlug()
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('/manage/shop/edit.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'shop' => $shop,

        ]);
    }
```

Today I can display the name of file already uploaded by using _shop_cover_widget and its attributes.

Ben when I check if my file already uploaded is include in the form the message is "no file selected"..

Thanks

Comment: When edit a shop, you must set image required false, if the user upload new one it will be updated in the database else it will be not updated and it remains as it is. So in you edit function you don't need any additional code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following exemple can help you, if you want the keep the older image uploaded without edit it

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_post_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $oldPost = $post->getImage();
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AdminBundle\Form\PostType', $post);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

        if($post->getImage() == null){
            $post->setImage($oldPost);
        }else{

            $file = $post->getImage();
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
            $file->move($this->getParameter('uploads_posts_directory') , $fileName); 
            $post->setImage($fileName);
        }

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_post_index');
    }

    return $this->render('post/edit.html.twig', array(
        'post' => $post,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```